# Grafana - show max value in selected range time

Tags: mysql, grafana

I am doing graphs in Grafana. I want to show max value in range which I select in dashboard. How can I do it?
My query:
`SELECT teplota FROM esp_teplota.teplota1;`
I have for "teplota" set Max in Calculation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is your goal.

If you want to use something like stat or gauge panels - just use your query and in panel options: Value options > Calculation > Select `Max`.

If you want to use something like table Use Transform > Reduce

```
Mode: Series to rows
Calculation: Max
```